# Создается ли prepared statement при обычном native запросе с параметрами в Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Использую `Hibernate 2`.У меня есть такой объект `query`:

```
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery.toString())
                        .setParameter("iata", flight.substring(0, 2))
                        .setParameter("flightNumber", flight.substring(2))
                        .setParameter("firstname", firstname)
```

Где `sqlQuery` - это какой-то `sql` запрос с параметрами, собранный через `StringBuilder`.

Нигде не могу найти информацию по следующему вопросу. Что происходит при получении данных при запросе `query.list()`? В смысле, будет ли создан `prepare statement` в базе [таким образом](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-prepare.html) и с дальнейшей посылкой только необходимых параметров без запроса ? Или каждый раз будет просто собираться строка с параметрами и происходить обычное обращение к базе без `prepare statement` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, создается. Включите логи Hibernate и в логах вы увидите, что создается `PreparedStatement`, типа:

```
select a, b, c from mytable where d=?
```

Вопросительный знак как раз указывает, что это `PreparedStatement` в escape нотации JDBC

**P.S.**

> Hibernate always uses PreparedStatement for calls to the database

[пруфлинк](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-PerformanceQA/version/1)

Comment: Окей, но ведь при каждом запросе к `query.list()` формируется текст  `session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery.toString())`. Получается, что у себя внутри `hibernate` сравнивает строку запроса с уже существующей ? Он где-то у себя сохраняет эти данные ? Или каждый раз создается новый `prepare statement` ?

Comment: Да, все верно. Он кэширует запросы. Если запрос у него уже есть в кэше, он извлечет его и не будет тратить время на повторную компиляцию. Размер кэша можно задавать в настройках - поройтесь в документации.

Comment: Немного не в тему. Не подскажите, почему часто пишут, что обращения к базе с Hibernate раз в 5-10 дольше, чем при голых запросах без `ORM` ? Он же все оптимизирует и кэширует.

Comment: Это вопрос из серии холиваров. С другой стороны, конечно, за все надо платить. Hibernate, как и любой ORM имеет свой оверхед вызовов. Плюс, на диалекте SQL всегда можно написать оптимизированный под конкретный СУБД запрос, а Hibernate ввиду своей универсальности не использует диалектные штучки.